# Is it method Overloading?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

Please find below is the sample code:-

```
class ExtendMe{
    public void printV(int x){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public class InheritOM extends ExtendMe {
    void printV(int y ,int z){
        System.out.println("2 arg method called");
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(z);
    }

    public static void main(String args []){
        InheritOM obj = new InheritOM();
        obj.printV(4);
        obj.printV(5,6); 
    }
}
```

Can i say that printV method is overloaded ?

Comment: Yes of course you can say that, as you are able to invoke both of them, right?

Comment: @Rohit, +1, yes i am able to invoke both of them. Wasn't aware that overloading works with Inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can say that.  The first sentence on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading tells you so.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, overloading works when trying to overload a method from a superclass.

Remember this, when talking about overloading:

- Overloaded methods MUST change the argument list.
- Overloaded methods CAN change the return type.
- Overloaded methods CAN change the access modifier.
- Overloaded methods CAN declare new or broader checked exceptions.

Comment: That's what i was saying. You MUST change the argument list to overload a method. I didn't say changing the `return type` overloads it.

Comment: @user1870638.. Ah! my bad. I didn't see `MUST` in the first condition. I take my comment back.

Comment: +1, i am aware of the bullets, the one thing that I wasn't aware was overloading method under inheritance, but now I know it. thanks for your time. :)